# Friend declaration of literal operator in class template

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, g++

I'm trying to make a class that can only be constructed through a literal operator, but it fails to build on gcc.

Here's a stripped down example:

```
#include <cstddef>

template<typename C>
class Foo;
Foo<char> operator "" _foo(const char*, std::size_t);

template<typename C>
class Foo
{
    Foo() = default;
    friend Foo<char> operator "" _foo(const char*, std::size_t);
};

Foo<char> operator "" _foo(const char* str, std::size_t size)
{
    return Foo<char>();
}

int main()
{
    auto foo = "Foo"_foo;
    return 0;
}
```

It fails with this message: https://godbolt.org/z/kfcNMR

```
<source>:11:22: error: 'Foo<char> operator""_foo(const char*, std::size_t)' has invalid argument list
```

It works on clang and msvc, and without the template it works on gcc: https://godbolt.org/z/exfm5Q

Is this a compiler bug or am I making a mistake?

Comment: I have a feeling it's a compiler bug. Clang accepts it.

Comment: Just a note, it works if you do a specialized `Foo<char>`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug and it was reported 5 years ago.

> Bug 61648 - g++ accepts literal operator friends for non-template
>   classes but not for *template* classes
>
> https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61648